# PHP does not upload my picture to the server

Tags: php, mysql, oop, file-upload, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to upload a picture, but it is not being uploaded. (When I click the "submit" button, the picture attachment on the screen becomes empty as if it is uploaded.)

I have already spent several days on this, but I can't figure out the problem.  Does anyone see a problem with my code?  (The codes below are excerpt of my code; I have excluded the codes for error messages to save space.)

Here is the code in my "upload.php" file:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="file" name="file_upload">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then from here the submitted file goes to:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$photo = new Photo();
$photo->title = $_POST['title'];
$photo->set_file($_FILES['file_upload']);
```

Then it is being received in "photo.php" file as follows:

```
public function set_file($file) {
$this->filename = basename($file['name']);
$this->tmp_path = $file['tmp_name'];
$this->type     = $file['type'];
$this->size     = $file['size'];
```

Once it gets to the database it is saved as follows:

```
public function save() {
$target_path = SITE_ROOT . DS . 'admin' . DS . $this->upload_directory . DS . $this->filename;
if(move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_path, $target_path)) { 
if($this->create()) {
unset($this->tmp_path);
return true; }}
```

Comment: "*but it is not being uploaded and returns empty*". What *returns* empty?

Comment: The picture attachment returns empty, so it looks like before attaching any  the picture.  However, I do receive a custom made error message that the directory probably does not have permissions.  Since the error message is  custom made,  it really doesn't help me.

Comment: Maybe you should dig into what triggers that error message. Could help.

Comment: Upload a picture from where to where? A *server* to another *server*? Within the *same* server itself? Your *local* and a *remote* server?

Comment: Can you remove the vote down on my question?  I did clarify the part that was unclear to you.  I don't want to be blocked from asking questions.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not the one who downvoted your question.

Comment: Can you give an up vote on my question to counter act the effect of the down vote considering the effort I made to clarify the question?  Do you have any idea why I  was given a down vote?  Thanks.

Comment: [You cannot request a user to up-vote your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271815/2788131) and [reasons to vote are personal, private](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267894/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-not-closed/267895#267895).

Comment: And [considering your revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32292753/revisions), you haven't made that much effort to clarify the question, and haven't done [what I suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292753/php-does-not-upload-my-picture-to-the-server?noredirect=1#comment52472845_32292753).

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux server, please check the folder permission.  For testing purpose, you may set it to 777 and try agian.

If you are using Mac, you should open folder info.  At the bottom, you may find the permission.  Change everyone permission to Read/Write.

Windows should have no permission problem.

Comment: I already set the Linux server folder permission to 777.  It didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer to the problem after one month.  My program did run well on Apple Mac and on GoDaddy web hosting site when someone else checked my program for me.  However, it did not run on Windows 10 on my new PC, and it did not run on my web hosting site.

I changed my web hosting site to GoDaddy web hosting site, which is at the top of the line, then my program ran very well and I could easily upload my pictures with PHP to the server.

The program apparently runs well on Windows 10 on other PCs, yet it does not run on my relatively new Dell PC, which I bought in mid 2015.  I also had serious problems with my previous Dell PC.  Apparently Dell is not a good PC.

So sometimes the problem is not because of a bug in the program, but it is because of an inferior PC or an inferior web hosting site.